# Is there any solution for calculate checksum?

Tags: c#, hex, checksum

I'm writing a SerialPort tool, And I got a problem that I don't know how to calculate the checksum...

For example:

| Flag | COMM ID | COMM Length | Data | Remain | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x55 | 0x00000003 | 0x0000001c | 32bit *3 | 0x00000000 | 0xFFFFFFDF |

The Data:

| Remain | Sub-Command | Remain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00000000 | 0x00000002 | 0x00000000 |

The Calculation method:
checksum, SUM=~((DWORD) COMM ID + (DWORD) COMM Length + (DWORD) Data + (DWORD)Sub-Command + (DWORD) Remain) +1

The result:
55 03 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF FF FF FF

**How can I get the sum(like 0xFFFFFFDF) with C#?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have already answered your own question, more or less, though your calculation method mentions both "data" and "subcommand", even though "subcommand" is *part* of "data".

```cs
int commId = 0x00000003;
int length = 0x0000001c;
int subcommand = 0x00000002;
int remain = 0x00000000;
            
// you said:
// ~((DWORD) COMM ID + (DWORD) COMM Length + (DWORD) Data + (DWORD)Sub-Command + (DWORD) Remain) +1
// you probably wanted Remain + Sub-Command + Remain though,
// as that is what Data is defined as.
int csum = ~(commId + length + remain + subcommand + remain) + 1;
            
Console.WriteLine(csum.ToString("X"));
```

produces the result -33, with the next value `FFFFFFDF`.

`DWORD` is simply a 32-bit integer, just like the standard C# `int` type. `~` is the unary negation operator.

Comment: Thank you a lot. someone must have hit my brain yesterday that made me ask this question